# Custom pagination with contains/joins and condition

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3, containable

I am trying to paginate some data from a model called D filtering results based on a specific condition from an indirectly related model.  My models look like:

D->C->B->A (where each -> is a belongs to)

I want to paginate on the records of D where A.client = ?

Is this possible using containable? What is the preferred method of doing this (using containable from model D resulted in a query for each paginated item, which seems inefficient)?

Comment: Yes. You can use containable to limit and trip the data fields in all your models. And in your condition just use it as normal. All fields that you "contain" will be available for use in pagination, find, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using Containable probably works; e.g.

```
// function in AController

$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('A.client' => 'foo'),
    'contain' => array(
        'B' => array(
            'C' => array(
                'D'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

CakePHP will join A to B, B to C, and C to D. I think it's probably the most straightforward way to get data that is 4 models away. As for inefficiency, you can use the sql_dump element in conjunction with 'explain plan' to make sure that your query uses indexes appropriately.